# How did the police get into the secure basement that Jessica Jones was locked inside?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones-2015

In Season 2 Episode 8 of Jessica Jones, how did the cops **break** through the door into the room where Jessica and her Mom were held when Jessica or her Mom couldn't **break**  that door?

Comment: Maybe it's just much much much easier to open from the outside? Umm, reminds me of a certain box that once held one of the most dangerous creature in the Universe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They didn't.  The door is secured on the outside with a bolt, so presumably they just undid that.  This can be clearly seen when Jessica arrives at the cellar in s2e6.

[image: Jessica approaches the cellar door]